# linq to sql transaction

Tags: c#, sql, linq, transactionscope

I have the following code below with different calls to stored procedures.

My problem is that I want this to be in a transaction, so if one of the DB methods fails then it will automatically rollback the pending changes.

I have read some articles on Stackoverflow/Microsoft pages which states that the SubmitChanges will wrap these in transactions for me.

The problem is that the spClearTablesForReplication method clears the tables and later on the code fails on purpose (for testing) and then all my tables are empty (is not rolled back)

```
XalSqlDataContext db = new XalSqlDataContext();
db.spClearTablesForReplication();
db.spUpdateStockItemGroup(ConvertToXElement(typeof(List<StockItemGroup>),    stockItemGroups));
db.spUpdateStockItemSubGroup(ConvertToXElement(typeof(List<StockItemSubGroup>),    stockItemSubGroups));

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Any clues/solutions for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your code in a `TransactionScope` using block and then that will rollback unless it reaches the point where you call `transactionScope.Complete()`.

Example:

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    //code here
    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: So if I do this then I don't need SubmitChanges anymore ?

Comment: @user1914109 Nothing else should change in your code. The operations that you feel should be transactional (all or nothing) you should wrap within a transactionScope using block, other than that the code you use now should not change.

Comment: So the conclusion SubmitChanges doesn't wrap the db calls in transactions ?

Comment: @user1914109 Yes, the SubmitChanges *does* wrap its own actions in a transaction, but it will use the ambiant transaction if there is one. That means that when you use a transaction scope the SubmitChanges will enlist in the transaction that is already running, and everything will happen in a single transaction.

Comment: Last question, should I still use SubmitChanges. If yes before or after transactionScope.Complete

Comment: @user1914109 Like i showed in the answer, the last thing called should be transactionScope.Complete(); So YES, before the call to Complete().